# Want to delete few lines above and below certain string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My requirement is to delete certain lines from my `nagios` file

Below mentioned is a part of my `hotname.cfg` file.
My requirement is to make a shell script to delete lines beginning from `"define host {" upto "}"`
and the variable input `( read )` to fetch from user is just the host_name which can differ.

here i want to delete all entries relevant to host_name --> hostname02x
so i need to delete entries relevant to it beginning from `"define host {" upto "}"` , so that the file which earlier look

```
#cat hostname.cfg

define host{
                use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                host_name               hostname01x
                hostgroups              COT-Servers
                contact_groups          admins
                alias                   FEA Preprod
             }

define host{
                use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                host_name               hostname02x
                hostgroups              COT-Servers
                contact_groups          admins
                alias                   Grid Engine
              }
```

looks like...

```
#cat hostname.cfg

define host{
                use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                host_name               hostname01x
                hostgroups              COT-Servers
                contact_groups          gecotadmins
                alias                   FEA Preprod
             }
```

I used several methods to delete such entry but none of my algorithms works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed :

```
sed '/define host/ {:a;/}/!{N;ba};/hostname02x/d}' hotname.cfg
```

It loops over all blocks from `/define host/` upto next `}` : each line in block is added to the pattern space with `N` and the pattern space matching `hostname02x` is deleted.

Explanation :

- `/define host/` : starting from `/define host/`
- `:a` : a label for upcoming loop
- `/}/!` : if `}` is not found...
- `N` : append the line to the pattern space
- `ba` : branch to label `a` to check if next line contains a `}`
- when loop ends, `}` has been found
- `/hostname02x/d` : deletes the pattern space if it matches `/hostname02x/`

Comment: Though -i  parameter was missing but i figured it out as i m too a "Seeder"  sed -i.bak  '/define host/ {:a;/}/!{N;ba};/hostname02x/d}' hotname.cfg works fine for me... Cheers now thsi gonna fed to a PHP script ;)

Comment: can you elaborate a little more about the parameters  '/define host/ {:a;/}/!{N;ba};/hostname02x/d}'

Answer (score 4):

this awk one-liner should work for given example:

```
awk -v RS="[}]\n" -v ORS="}\n" '!/hostname02x/' hostname.cfg
```

The idea is, make the `{...}` block as a record, and check if the record has `hostname02x`, we skip the record.

Comment: Kent, it just grep the output but doesn't deletes from file.

Comment: @KunalSaha you need redirect like this `awk '...' hn.cfg > /tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo hn.cfg` give it a try

Comment: grep -A3 -B3 hostname02x hostname.cfg gives the same output but can't redirect the needful.

Comment: @KunalSaha I won't use grep with `-A -B`  in this case, unless you are sure that the data block format won't be changed, like adding/removing an attribute or block contains empty line(s)...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a shell script, try this

```
#!/bin/bash
awk  -v hostname=$2 'BEGIN{RS="}\n"}!($0~hostname) {if($0!="\n"){printf "%s}\n",$0}}' $1 >tempfile.cfg
mv tempfile.cfg $1
```

Save the script as, say, `remove_host`

and run it as

```
./remove_host hostname.cfg host_to_remove
```